# How to extract the argument list in variadic templates for n-dimensional array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, g++-4.7

I have a template class with the following specification:

```
template <typename T, size_t... Dims> class Array;
```

And say it can be used as follows:

```
// Define a 2X3X4 array of integers.  Elements are uninitialized.
Array<int, 2, 3, 4> a, b;
Array<short, 2, 3, 4> c;
Array<int, 0> e1; // This line must cause a compile-time error.
```

How can I achieve this functionality? I thought if I could extract all the argument list I could then create the n-dimentional array as a straight forward recursive call. How can I do it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a compile-time trait that does what you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t... Ts>
struct not_zero {};

template <std::size_t N>
struct not_zero<N> : std::integral_constant<bool, N> {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ts>
struct not_zero<N, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<bool, N && not_zero<Ts...>::value> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Ts>
struct Array
{
    static_assert(not_zero<Ts...>::value, "Dimension cannot be 0");
};

template struct Array<int, 3>; // OK
template struct Array<int, 3, 2, 1, 0>; // error: static assertion failed: Dimension cannot be 0
```

See a demo [here](http://ideone.com/AFvO1t#view_edit_box).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe

```
namespace mine {

    template<typename T, size_t first, size_t... rest>
    struct multi_array__ {
        enum { dims = sizeof...(rest) };
        static_assert(first,"dimension can not be zero!"); 
        typedef std::array< typename multi_array__<T, rest...>::type, first > type;
    };


    template<typename T, size_t first>
    struct multi_array__<T,first> {
        enum { dims = 1 };
        static_assert(first,"dimension can not be zero!"); 
        typedef std::array<T,first> type;
    };

    template <typename T, std::size_t... ds> 
    using multi_array = typename multi_array__<T, ds ...>::type;

};
```

You can use it like this

```
mine::multi_array <int,2,3,4> arr1 = {};
// multi_array<int,2,3,0,4> arr3;  // This fails
mine::multi_array <int,3,4> arr2 = {};
```

Assignments like this work too

```
arr2[0] = arr1[0][0];
```

[**`Here`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e09e0679a97cb96b5df8dbe127d8aa17-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59) is a simple test program.

Comment: Augment this answer with `template <typename T, std::size_t... ds>
using Array = typename multi_array<T, ds ...>::type;`, and then you don't need to use `::type`.

Comment: @sftrabbit That is actually a very nice trick. Thank you for that. didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Create a specialization for it:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
struct Array {};

template <typename T>
struct Array<T, 0>; // leave as an incomplete type

int main()
{
    Array<int, 3> x; // OK
    Array<int, 0> y; // error: aggregate ‘Array<int, 0u> y’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
}
```